# spring security different login message

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to have different login error messages such as 'Login Failed' or 'Internal System Error'. Or maybe even the ability to redirect to a different page. I tried to follow what was done here http://www.codemarvels.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-how-to-display-login-errors/ except that I don't have form-login tag, so I wasn't able to set authentication-failure-handler-ref as show on the page. However, I did set authenticationFailureHandler(to use ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler) on FORM_LOGIN_FILTER which is a custom class that just extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

What am I missing here?

EDIT-09/19/2013: I did a little bit of debugging, and I'm asking the wrong question. It appears that it's working fine. However, I have multiple authentication providers, and the exception from the first one, is overwritten with the exception from the second one. Basically, I'm trying to simulate DB down exception, which is thrown, but then authentication against Active Directory is attempted which is up, and I just get user not found exc. Hence, I don't get my AuthenticationServiceException.

I guess my question at this point is how do I make the exception from the first one stick without changing the order of providers (the DB providers is used for majority of users).

```
<http pattern="/**"  authentication-manager-ref='testAuthenticationManager' entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customFormLoginFilter" />
     <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
 </http>

<!-- This just extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter -->
<beans:bean id="customFormLoginFilter" class="com.acme.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter" >
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="testAuthenticationManager"/>    
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>        
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />        
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/login.jsp?errorCode=maxSessionsExceeded" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
     <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login/setup.htm"/>
    <beans:property  name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>        
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="failureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException">/login.jsp?errorCode=666</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: what happen in case of authentication failure with the above config ?

Comment: See my edit from 09/19/2013. The config I have is fine. the reason I don't get the exception I was expecting is because I have multiple authentication providers. How do I make the exception from the first provider stick w/o changing the order of providers?

Comment: Seems like there is a way to break out of the Authentication Provider loop by throwing AccountStatusException. that's pretty much what I was looking for.